# Iterate an array with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, math, grep

I'm new to jquery and I'm having trouble applying certain methods.
I'm trying to go through the operators I have in a dragable layer to get their right and so get the maximum value of all of them to be able to make a later calculation. 
It is giving me back all the operators that are in the layer, when what I am looking for is to get the one that has the highest value.
This is my code:

```
var operatorLayer = containerParent.find('.main-operators-layer')[0];
operatorsData = $(operatorLayer).children('.main-operator'); 

var actualContainerWidth = $.grep(operatorsData, function(element, index) {
     var rightValues = [];
     var rightOffsetData = element.getBoundingClientRect().right;
     rightValues.push(rightOffsetData);
     Math.max(rightValues);
     return rightValues;
});
```

If anyone can correct me, I'd appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: Is rightOffsetData an array? if so just use Math.max on that.

Comment: I've try it                                                                                                               
```
var actualContainerWidth = $.grep(operatorsData, function(element, index) {
                    var rightOffsetData = element.getBoundingClientRect().right;
                    return Math.max(rightOffsetData);
                });  
```                                                                                                                                   
but it still returns to me all the operators in the layer.

Comment: what does rightOffsetData look like?

Comment: in this case , with 3 operators on the layer  returns an array like this           
         [div.main-operator.operator-0.main-default-operator.ui-draggable, div.main-operator.operator-1.main-default-operator.ui-draggable, div.main-operator.operator-2.main-default-operator.ui-draggable]

Comment: Math.max `returns` the maximum; it does not transform the input *into* the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery manual](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) tells me `grep`:

> Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.

The function you pass into `grep` is supposed to return a boolean, true or false, to tell whether we keep the element or not.

In your case, you seem to return `[element.getBoundingClientRect().right]`:

- `var rightValues = [];` makes a new empty array
- `var rightOffsetData = element.getBoundingClientRect().right; rightValues.push(rightOffsetData);` adds `right` to the array
- `Math.max(rightValues);` calculates (and then ignores) the highest number in the array with 1 item
- `return rightValues;` returns an array with one entry, which is not false, thus the entry is kept

What you presumably want is something like:

- Make a list of `rightOffsetData` values
- Calculate the highest of those values

That would come down to something like this:

```
var actualContainerWidth = Math.max($.map(operatorsData, function(element) {
  return element.getBoundingClientRect().right;
}));
```

It uses [the `map` function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

> Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

- `$.map(operatorsData, function(element) { return element.getBoundingClientRect().right; })` transforms the list of operatorsData into a list of their bounding-thingy-right
- `Math.max(...)` takes the highest value form that list
- `var actualContainerWidth = Math.max(...)` makes `actualContainerWidth` take that value

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation! it works perfectly and the explanation couldn't be better!